# « [...] et je puis vous dire qu'elle en vaudra mieux » : sens, formulation ?

Tags: sens, histoire, québec, locutions, france

Il y a cinquante ans cette année, le 23 juillet 1967 (année de l'[Exposition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposition_universelle_de_1967) Universelle), le général [de Gaulle](http://fresques.ina.fr/de-gaulle/fresque), alors Président de la République (1959-1969), [débarque](http://fresques.ina.fr/de-gaulle/fiche-media/Gaulle00136/voyage-du-general-de-gaulle-au-quebec.html) du croiseur [*Colbert*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colbert_(croiseur)) (bâtiment amiral de l'*Escadre de la Méditerranée*) au port de la ville de Québec pour une visite au Canada ; c'est la première visite officielle d'un chef d'État français au Québec. Il empruntera ensuite, le 24 au matin, le [*Chemin du Roy*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemin_du_Roy), soit le chemin reliant [Québec](http://fresques.ina.fr/de-gaulle/fiche-media/Gaulle00152/voyage-a-quebec) à [Montréal](http://fresques.ina.fr/de-gaulle/fiche-media/Gaulle00135/voyage-a-montreal) par la rive nord du *Fleuve*, lors de son voyage [mythique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wonkoXuO7Cc) se terminant avec son [discours légendaire](http://www.charles-de-gaulle.org/pages/l-homme/accueil/discours/le-president-de-la-cinquieme-republique-1958-1969/discours-de-montreal-vive-le-quebec-libre-23-juillet-1967.php) de Montréal, qu'en fait il ne [devait pas](https://youtu.be/W5R26LLgyEQ?t=41m50s) prononcer, du [balcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l1EYNoHY1A) de l'Hôtel de ville, et dont voici la fin :

> [...] Et, d'ailleurs, le concours que la France va, tous les jours un peu
>   plus, prêter ici, elle sait bien que vous le lui rendrez, parce que
>   vous êtes en train de vous constituer des élites, des usines, des
>   entreprises, des laboratoires, qui feront l'étonnement de tous et qui,
>   un jour, j'en suis sûr, vous permettront d'aider la France.
>
> Voilà ce que je suis venu vous dire ce soir en ajoutant que j'emporte
>   de cette réunion inouïe de Montréal un souvenir inoubliable. La France
>   entière sait, voit, entend, ce qui se passe ici et je puis vous dire
>   qu'*elle en vaudra mieux*.
>
> Vive Montréal ! Vive le Québec !
>
> Vive le Québec libre !
>
> Vive le Canada français ! et vive la France !
>
> [ Le général de Gaulle (Président de la République), lors du *Discours de
>   Montréal ("Vive le Québec libre!")*, 24 juillet 1967, je souligne un passage ]

---

On connaît *valoir [mieux](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mieux/51376/locution?q=valoir%20mieux#181652)* dans le sens d'*être préférable* en parlant de quelque chose, ou en forme impersonnelle ; on connaît *un tien vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras*, où le verbe [valoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valoir) est conjugué avec la chose comme sujet. On peut imaginer *avoir plus de valeur/mérite* en parlant d'une personne par comparaison à une autre, ou par rapport à un moment précis dans le temps. Mais sans un tel repère et avec un pronom personnel, j'ai une certaine difficulté à comprendre, comme dans l'exemple « *Neuve elle* [la noblesse] *se vendait alors ; elle valait [mieux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mieux)* » (Courier) dans le sens d'« [a]voir plus de valeur, d'avantages, de qualités » : c'est que *mieux* n'est pas exactement *plus* a priori, mais on comprend quand même que la valeur était davantage contemporaine de la nouveauté et qu'elle s'est étiolée.

Sauf que dans le discours du Général, la France est le sujet du verbe au futur avec le pronom *en* alors qu'on est même incertain si ce dernier réfère au fait que la *France sait, voit, entend*, où s'il est tributaire d'une autre idée de construction, comme avec *se [porter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter)/tirer* en emploi pronominal, ou *[tirer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirer) profit de* par exemple. Ce qui fait qu'au final c'est inusité pour moi, que le sens de la fin de la phrase m'échappe et n'eût été de la retranscription puis d'une écoute attentive par la suite je l'aurais toujours compris comme la forme impersonnelle *il en vaudra mieux* (il(ce) sera préférable). Mais on dit bien *Elle*.

---

- Quand on parle de la France comme d'un sujet, est-ce qu'il y a
  généralement anthropomorphisme, est-ce pertinent ici et est-ce que ça
  oriente le sens ?
- Que veut dire *une [personne] (en) vaudra mieux* dans l'abstrait,
  sans complément ni infinitif qui ne suive et si c'est inconcevable doit-il alors s'agir d'une ellipse ; l'apport du pronom *en* y change-t-il quoi que ce soit et peut-on l'analyser dans le discours ?
- Que veut dire exactement « qu'elle en vaudra mieux » ici ; ce tour est-il usuel ; peut-on reformuler ou présenter un terme/verbe équivalent ?

Answer (score 1):

Le tour n'est pas usuel mais je le comprends comme signifiant que la valeur de la France serait accrue après qu'elle ait su, vu et entendu ce qui se disait à Montréal.

Plus simplement, de Gaulle voulait dire que le développement économique et politique du Québec allait enrichir (aussi) la France.

Comment: Merci ! La précision que le tour n'est pas nécessairement des plus usuels est réconfortante je dirais. _Enrichir_ avec le complément direct, c'est limpide et juste à mon avis.

Answer (score 1):

- L'anthropomorphisme n'est pas général, mais plutôt un effet de style pour ce discours. Ceci dit, la France est parfois personnifiée, en la personne de [Marianne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne).
- Pour *en vaudra mieux* dans l'abstrait, je ne sais pas, je ne crois pas avoir jamais entendu cette expression.
- Pour *en vaudra mieux* dans ce contexte, mon interprétation serait que la France bénéficiera de savoir tout ce qui se passe au Québec, qu'elle en sortira *grandie*, *meilleure*.

  Pour l'interprétation "*enrichir*" de jlliagre, il ne s'agit bien entendu pas de mercantilisme. Je pense que de Gaulle avait une vision plus grande, et pensait à un "enrichissement" au sens le plus large, pas seulement financier.

Comment: Imaginez que je ne savais pourquoi j'adorais ce nom, mais maintenant je sais. Oui, j'avais aussi compris un sens plus large, au figuré, d'_enrichir_. Merci !

Comment: J'avais bien sûr moi aussi en tête le sens élargi d'enrichir lorsque j'ai écrit ma réponse. Après l'avoir relue, j'ai vu que l'on pouvait ne comprendre que le sens financier du terme et c'est pour cela que j'ai rajouté « et politique » lors de mon édition; de Gaulle parle bien sûr aussi d'enrichissement culturel, de la « grandeur » de la France qui lui tenait à cœur.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding its abstract meaning with a person, in a way that I find similar to that of General de Gaulle’s, in a letter to Monsieur Jean-Bernard, abbé Le Blanc,  Voltaire uses “en valent mieux” positively  in a sentence to describe two people and the expected results when they learn more about each other’s  countries  :

> Je crois qu'un Anglais qui a bien vu la France, et un Français qui a
>   bien vu l'Angleterre, **en valent mieux** l'un et l'autre.

(from * Œuvres complètes de Voltaire: Correspondance*, by Voltaire, Jean Michel Moreau, Louis Moland, Georges Bengesco, Adrien Jean Quentin Beuchot, via *GoogleBooks*)

If pressed to translate Voltaire’s use of "en valoir mieux" in that sentence to English, I think I’d use:

“are [only] better-off for it” or

“are [all] the better for it,”

either of which could lead back to the notion of [“ne s'en portent que mieux”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter) in French:

> CNTRL/TFLi’s entry for “porter”
>     3eSection. Empl. pronom.
>   I. − [Désigne un état]
>     A. …
>     ♦ Ne s'en porter que mieux. Se trouver dans
>   un excellent état, en dépit de conditions ou d'événements qui
>   devraient avoir une influence néfaste.

Granted, this expression, unlike its English equivalent, strongly implies, even requires, the presence of “une influence néfaste,” and the General was well advised not to use “qu’elle ne s'en portera que mieux”  in his famous speech, as it might have sounded like he was saying that the fact that all of France was “knowing, seeing, and hearing” the events in Quebec was somehow a bad thing.

I do, however, think the “Se trouver dans un excellent état" part of the expression’s meaning captures well what he meant by "en vaudra mieux” in that speech.

Comment: « Il faut parler peu, il le faut absolument. » (de Gaulle). Indeed I find the General a very clever speaker and writer, and it feels like he's very much in command of the language, so to speak. Sometimes there's like a nexus of overlapping possible phrasing that add layers to the fabric of meaning. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

« Qu'elle en vaudra mieux »
«ELLE», définitivement, le Général parle de LA FRANCE.
Notre Premier Ministre l'avait rencontré à ses bureaux de l'Élysée.  Ces échanges ne sont pas tous connus.

« ÉGALITÉ ou INDÉPENDANCE » un livre de Daniel Johnson fait l'éloge et l'obligation d'aller plus loin, plus haut à l'international. Ce concept, il le connaît, le Général. Il parcourt le monde et tous ses discours parlent d'émancipation de chacun des Pays.

Au Québec, par sa traversée tout le long du Chemin du Roy et la rencontre de millions de citoyens tout le long du parcours et l'enthousiasme de notre population à son égard, IL A VÉCU ce qu'il a appelé les moments de LIBÉRATION de la France.
VIVRE cela vient chercher tous les éléments intérieurs des personnes et encore plus le GÉNÉRAL.  Il sait de quoi il parle.  Il sait ce qu'il a ressenti, vécu toutes les minutes de son séjours chez nous.

ON A AIMÉ LE GÉNÉRAL et il l'a ressenti.  Il l'a proclamé à sa façon. Les QUÉBÉCOIS aiment la FRANCE, celle que nous a montré par sa présence et son esprit, le GÉNÉRAL CHARLES DE GAULLE.

Il en VAUDRA MIEUX si nous travaillons ENSEMBLE.

ÉGALITÉ ou INDÉPENDANCE donne toute la latitude au Canada de jouer un rôle dynamique de reconnaissance de notre réalité QUÉBÉCOISE, FRANÇAISE, en Amérique du Nord.
On ne se reniera pas pour satisfaire quiconque.  NOUS SOMMES QUÉBÉCOIS, 100% QUÉBÉCOIS en terre d'Amérique.
Au besoin, j'ajouterai si l'on veut bien échanger ensemble.

Comment: Les majuscules, pourquoi ?  Est-ce que ça répond à la question du sens ?